# How to use sections properly in a layout hierarchy in ASP.NET Core MVC Razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a multi-level hierarchical layout inheritance:

```
Layout.cshtml

MaterialLayout.cshtml // inherits Layout.cshtml

UserPanelLayout.cshtml // inherits MaterialLayout.cshtml

Index.cshtml // inherits UserPanelLayout.cshtml
```

I have defined a section in `Layout.cshtml` say `@RenderSection("Loader", false)`, and I want to define that section in `UserPanelLayout.cshml`.

But I get this error:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by
>   the page at '/Views/Shared/MaterialLayout.cshtml': 'Loader'. To ignore
>   an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").

What is the proper way to use sections in a multi-level hierarchical layout inheritance?

Comment: @AshleyMedway, my guess is that it's the other way around. It starts from `UserPanelLayout.cshtml`, then it sees that `Loader` section is defined. Then it goes up one level into inheritance and expects `MaterialLayout.cshtml` to have rendered that section, that is, it expects to see `RenderSection("Loader", false)` inside `MaterialLayout.cshtml`.

Comment: Yeah misread, answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve this you need define the section in `MaterialLayout.cshtml` like this:

```
@section Loader
{
    @RenderSection("Loader", false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works very well for simple section definitions. Yet for some complex scenarios including `IsSectionDefined` usage and branching and default values etc. this doesn't seem to be a good way. Is this the only possible way?

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli I believe this is the only way to do this with an inherited style like you are going for, personally I would try to break down my structure. Trying to switch out much of the chained inheritance for `Html.Partial` or `Html.Action`, or if possible try to have all your `@RenderSection` in `MaterialLayout.cshtml` and not `Layout.cshtml`. However, I guess that would require you to dramatically rewrite a lot of the layouts.

Comment: Or you could go quick and dirty and use `ViewBag` to determine if a section should be shown rather than `IsSectionDefined`